# Functors, forming a pair "coretraction-retraction", what are they called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $I$ and $K$ be two categories. Let us consider two functors from $I$ to $K$:

- a covariant functor ${\mathcal F}:I\to K$, and
- a contravariant functor ${\mathcal G}:I\to K$,

and suppose that for each morphism $\varphi:A\to B$ in $I$ the following equalities hold:
$$
{\mathcal F}(A)={\mathcal G}(A),\quad {\mathcal F}(B)={\mathcal G}(B),
$$
$$
{\mathcal G}(\varphi)\circ {\mathcal F}(\varphi)=1_{{\mathcal F}(A)}
$$
In other words, ${\mathcal G}(\varphi)$ is a retraction for ${\mathcal F}(\varphi)$ (and ${\mathcal F}(\varphi)$ is a coretraction for ${\mathcal G}(\varphi)$).

Question:

> what is such a pair of functors $({\mathcal F},{\mathcal G})$ called?

---

Let me give an example that I have in mind. Suppose $G$ is an LP-group, i.e. a locally compact group which is a projective limit of its Lie quotient groups. Denote by $\lambda(G)$ the system of compact normal subgroups $H$ in $G$ such that the quotient group $G/H$ is a Lie group. Then,
$$
G=\projlim_{H\in\lambda(G)}G/H.
$$
We endow $\lambda(G)$ with the partial order
$$
H\le L\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad H\supseteq L,
$$
and this allows to consider $\lambda(G)$ as a category.

Now let us consider the space ${\mathcal C}(G)$ of continuous functions on $G$ and for each group $H\in\lambda(H)$ let us denote by ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$ the subspace of functions in ${\mathcal C}(G)$ which are invariant with respect to the shifts on elements of $H$:
$$
u(g\cdot h)=u(g)=u(h\cdot g),\qquad g\in G, \ h\in H
$$
We can note that
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\cong{\mathcal C}(G/H),\qquad H\in\lambda(G).
$$

Now we can define the functor ${\mathcal F}$ as the one that turns $H\in\lambda(H)$ into the space ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$ and the pair $H\le L$ into the natural emdedding
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\subseteq {\mathcal C}(G:L)
$$
And the functor ${\mathcal G}$ again turns $H\in\lambda(H)$ into the space ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$, but the pair $H\le L$ is turned into the natural projection
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\gets {\mathcal C}(G:L)
$$
that turns each function $u\in{\mathcal C}(G:L)$ into its mean value with respect to the subgroup $H$:
$$
{\mathcal G}(H,L)(u)(g)=\int_H u(g\cdot h) \ \mu_H(d h),\qquad g\in G
$$
(here $\mu_H$ is the normalized Haar measure on $H$).

I am interested in this construction because it is used in Harmonic Analysis for proving some untrivial results, for example François Bruhat in his [paper of 1961](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1961__89__43_0) uses this to prove that the space ${\mathcal D}(G)$ of test functions on a locally compact group $G$ is complete. (But he replaces everywhere ${\mathcal C}(G)$ by ${\mathcal D}(G)$.)

I thought that perhaps this construction has a special name in category theory since it looks very natural.

---

**Remark.** I used the term "coretraction-retraction" in the title, but I think it's worth saying that this is not a "true coretraction-retraction pair", since this is not a situation when the composition of functors gives the identity functor: we can't write
$$
{\mathcal G}\circ {\mathcal F}=\operatorname{id}_I.
$$

P.S. I also asked this at [MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449647/functors-forming-pairs-coretraction-retraction-what-are-they-called).

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: this is actually Trivial.. Have you considered the definitions of retraction and co-*?

Comment: @varkor I have edited the text.

Comment: @Snared this looks very natrual, I thought there must be a special name for this.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I do think this definition looks natural, but I can't recall having seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

Why isn't it just *one* functor?

Consider the category $\mathsf{Top}_{mr}$ consisting of topological spaces and morphisms $f:X \rightarrow Y$ given by e**m**bedding **r**etraction pairs $X\overset{m}{\rightarrow} Y \overset{r}{\rightarrow} X$ (note both $m$ *and* $r$ are part of the datum of $f$!).

You define a functor $\mathcal{C}(G:-):\lambda(G) \rightarrow \mathsf{Top}_{mr}$, which sends $H\in\lambda(G)$ to $\mathcal{C}(G:H)=\mathcal{C}(G/H)$ and which sends any inclusion $L \subseteq H$ to the embedding-retraction pair $\mathcal{C}(G:H) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(G:L) \overset{avg}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{C}(G:H)$.

Note that you can still obtain your functors $\cal F$ and $\cal G$ by composing $\mathcal{C}(G:-)$ with the projections $\mathsf{Top}_{mr} \rightarrow \mathsf{Top}$ (which forgets the retractions) and $\mathsf{Top}_{mr} \rightarrow \mathsf{Top}^\text{op}$ (which forgets the embeddings).

Comment: Jonas, by composition of the pairs $f=(m_f,r_f)$ and $g=(m_g,r_g)$ I suppose you mean
$$
g\circ f=(m_g\circ m_f, r_f\circ r_g)
$$
- right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :) And identities are supposed to be given by the pairs $(id,id)$

Comment: Yes,  this is a simplification.

Comment: Jonas, however, this point of view seems to be not fruitful here, because my construction is aimed to pass to the injective limit of ${\mathcal F}$ and the projective limit of ${\mathcal G}$
and to consider a natural morphism between them 
$$
\injlim {\mathcal F}\to \projlim {\mathcal G}.
$$
One could expect that this corresponds to the injective limit of your functor in your category, but in the situation that I described this injective limit does not exist (while both limits for ${\mathcal F}$ and ${\mathcal G}$ exist in the usual category of locally convex spaces).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something... What is the injective limit of your functor in your category?

Comment: I cannot follow. The only projective limit I see in your question is about recovering $G$ from $\lambda(G)$ and has nothing to do with $\cal F,G$. You were asking, how to call the data you were describing and my answer is: a functor. Can you maybe elaborate a bit, what this injective / projective limit business is about?

Comment: Jonas, excuse me I was inaccurate in explaining what I need. F.Bruhat's theorem is about the injective limit of the functor ${\mathcal F}$ (if we replace the spaces ${\mathcal C}(...)$ by the spaces ${\mathcal D}(...)$). And if we translate what he does to the categorical language, this will be the study of the connection between the injective limit of ${\mathcal F}$ and the projective limiit of ${\mathcal G}$.

Comment: In the example that I described the injective limit of ${\mathcal F}$ in the category of locally convex spaces is the union of the spaces ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$:
$$
\injlim {\mathcal F}=\bigcup_{H\in\lambda(G)}{\mathcal C}(G:H)
$$
with the strongest locally convex topology for which all the injections of the spaces ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$ into this space are continuous.

Comment: The projective limit of the functor ${\mathcal G}$ is a bit complicated but there is a natural linear continuous mapping (a morphism)
$$
\injlim {\mathcal F}\to \projlim {\mathcal G}
$$
Can those limits in the category of locally convex spaces be reconstructed from your functor in your category?

Comment: Alright. I am not familiar with this particular theorem. But I think the functors are still there. You can obtain $\cal F$ by considering the projection $\mathsf{Top}_{mr} \rightarrow \mathsf{Top}$ forgetting the retractions. You can also obtain $\cal G$ by considering the projection $\mathsf{Top}_{mr} \rightarrow \mathsf{Top}^\text{op}$ forgetting the embeddings...

Comment: Ah, yes... OK, I need some time to think about this.